# Проблемы с кодировкой - русские буквы заменены на цифры и латиницу

Tags: php, java, кодировка, post

Отправляем post-запрос

```
String params = "a=save&str=" + str + "&table=" + table;
URL url = new URL(Program.site + "ldapadmin/save.php");
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(params.getBytes().length));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "ru-RU");
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.connect();
try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())) {
    dos.writeBytes(params);
    dos.flush();
 }
```

В php-файле, кодировка которого - utf-8 без BOM прописано header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
Проблема в том, что при передаче post-запроса каждый русский символ заменится. Например, если передать алфавит, php-файл примет "0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDE...". Как будто смещение какое-то. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться уже с этой кодировкой!

Comment: попробуйте закодировать запрос в хекс последовательность символов.

Comment: как это сделать? помогите пожалуйста, я в кодировках вообще не силён. И случайно ничего не случится с обычными латинскими символами? Они то верно передаются...

Comment: В `getBytes` можно подать кодировку, в вашем случае должно подойти `getBytes(StandardCharsetes.UTF-8)`, и вместо `DataOutputStream` лучше воспользовать обычным `OutputStream`, так как DOS отправляет сообщения предназначеные для чтения через `DataInputStream` коим php явно не является (хотя но счёт writeBytes я не уверен, но лучше перестраховаться)

Comment: @gt22 OutputStream это же абстрактный класс. Какой именно из его потомков лучше использовать?

Comment: `Я имею ввиду `connection.getOutputSteam()`

Answer (score 0):

как же легко всё оказалось!

```
dos.write(params.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```